# Most efficient way to check if row exists in grid Java

Tags: java, grid, contains

All,

I am wondering what's the most efficient way to check if a row already exists in a List<Set<Foo>>. A Foo object has a key/value pair(as well as other fields which aren't applicable to this question). Each Set in the List is unique.

As an example:

```
List[
 Set<Foo>[Foo_Key:A, Foo_Value:1][Foo_Key:B, Foo_Value:3][Foo_Key:C, Foo_Value:4]
 Set<Foo>[Foo_Key:A, Foo_Value:1][Foo_Key:B, Foo_Value:2][Foo_Key:C, Foo_Value:4]
 Set<Foo>[Foo_Key:A, Foo_Value:1][Foo_Key:B, Foo_Value:3][Foo_Key:C, Foo_Value:3]
]
```

I want to be able to check if a new Set (Ex: Set[Foo_Key:A, Foo_Value:1][Foo_Key:B, Foo_Value:3][Foo_Key:C, Foo_Value:4]) exists in the List.

Each Set could contain anywhere from 1-20 Foo objects.  The List can contain anywhere from 1-100,000 Sets. Foo's are not guaranteed to be in the same order in each Set (so they will have to be pre-sorted for the correct order somehow, like a TreeSet)

Idea 1: Would it make more sense to turn this into a matrix?  Where each column would be the Foo_Key and each row would contain a Foo_Value?
Ex:

```
A B C
-----
1 3 4
1 2 4
1 3 3
```

And then look for a row containing the new values?

Idea 2: Would it make more sense to create a hash of each Set and then compare it to the hash of a new Set?

Is there a more efficient way I'm not thinking of?

Thanks

Comment: Your idea 2 is what would happen if you used a LinkedHashSet instead of a List (and just called contains(newSet)). It would indeed probably be faster than the List.contains call, but you must make sure that the sets and their elements, once added to the LinkedHashSet, are never modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `TreeSets` for your `Sets` can't you just do `list.contains(set)` since a `TreeSet` will handle the `equals` check?

Also, consider using Guava's MultSet class.[Multiset](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html)

Comment: I don't think I would be able to in my case.  Each Foo contains other fields which may not make the Foo's equal (The key/values are the same but other fields are not).  I cannot override the equals as the other fields are necessary for comparison in other places.  I'm guessing this forces me to iterate them and do something with a custom hash directly...?

Comment: I think you are facing a larger problem... Whatever you have defined in equals is what Set is going to use to enforce that once one instance exists in the Set at a time. If there are two ideas of "equal" and the non-standard (the one is "equals") is not used for the purpose of the Set, the Set will not work.

Comment: Correct.  I was going to loop through each sets key/values, and create a hash that would encompass the whole set

Comment: That's not my point. A `Set` generally operates on the hashCode / equals contract. If you want the Set to act as a `Set` then you need to implement hashCode / equals appropriately for the `Set`. Otherwise, you should use a `List` or `Lists`.

Comment: The thinking there is I would have a list of unique hashes.  When I get a new Foo, I create a hash the same way and check it against the list of existing Foos.  This is 'faster' since you never have to loop through all Set data more than once, but there is a hit for building the hashes and as Kdansky mentioned below, it may not be worth it if loops are fast enough

Comment: gotcha.  I guess it would be a List of Lists in this case

Comment: Two non-equal elements may have the same hash value.

Comment: Re: List of Lists, that is what a Multimap gives you. You might want to check it out.

Comment: What I suggest, is that you look into Guava. If you were to use a `Predicate`, you could use the `find` method in `Iterables`.

Comment: Isn't it rare to have hash value collision?  I figure it would be more unique if I did something like: overallHashForSet = [hash[Foo#1keyValue]+hash[Foo#2keyValue]+etc...]

Comment: I will check out Guava Predicates and MultiMap

Comment: A good hash function will give "rare" collisions (obviously dependent on your collection size) but there is nothing that says that in a collection of two elements, they have the same hash. Re: collection size, if your collection size is greater than Integer.MAX, you are guaranteed collisions.

Comment: Adding the hashes of two elements in no way decreases the chance of collision: 1 + 5 + 7 = 2 + 3 + 8

Comment: Maybe I'm not using the term hash correctly.  I would sort the row based on some criteria, build a unique String based on the key/values and then take the hashcode of the unique String... or use the String as the 'hash'

Comment: Any time you use a hashCode, you have the potential for collision. If you are converting the object into a String using the fields, then the String's value should be unique unless the two objects are truly equal. Therefore, rather than using the hash on the String, just do an equals on the String.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use a less weird data structure. As for finding stuff: Generally Hashes or Sorting + Binary Searching or Trees are the ways to go, depending on how much insertion/deletion you expect. Read a book on basic data structures and algorithms instead of trying to re-invent the wheel.

Lastly: If this is not a purely academical question, Loop through the lists, and do the comparison. Most likely, that is acceptably fast. Even 100'000 entries will take a fraction of a second, and therefore not matter in 99% of all use cases.

I like to quote Knuth: **Premature optimisation is the root of all evil.**

Comment: Unfortunately that is how the db/java objects are designed and this is a special use case which is not normal.  I assume that creating a hash per row would be faster in the long-run for lookups, but as you said I don't want to reinvent the wheel if the for loops work.  I'll give them a try and see how it goes.